# Как интегрировать Swagger в Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, swagger

1. Имеется java проект на Spring
2. К проекту подключен Swagger
3. Теперь нужно подключить проект к Jenkins, получилось только добавить просто проект (папки, файлы и т.д.), а нужно чтобы там появился интерфейс Swagger

Как это сделать? Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно поднять статичный web сервис Swagger UI для вашего swagger yaml file.